# Have I specified my random effects correctly in my lmer model?

Tags: r, self-study, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I've run an experiment where participants (`PP`) viewed 40 quotes (`Item`) and rated them (`Rating`). Subjects were split into two groups where the font of the quotes was manipulated (`Font`). For both groups, the quotes they viewed were of two types (`QuoteType`) and also of two varying metrics (`Metrics`). This led to a total of four exposures - two `Font` groups where `Metrics` were counterbalanced, and thus 160 variations of stimuli (40 x 2 x 2).

My hypothesis is that `Rating` can be predicted as a product of a `Font`*`QuoteType` interaction. My secondary hypothesis is that a significant effect of `Metrics` should also emerge. I have no problems specifying my fixed effects - which have been contrast coded - but I am uncertain about the random effects. Here's my lmer model:

```
lmer(Rating~Font*QuoteType + Metrics + (1+QuoteType|PP) + (1+Font|Item), ProfJData)
```

I specified `(1+QuoteType|PP`) as I imagined that every `PP`'s intercept will differ by `QuoteType`, and the same for `Item`. However, since `|` refers to "within each" - i.e, grouping variable - and since my `Font` variable is a between-subjects factor, should I not be specifying the model like so?

```
lmer(Rating~Condition*QuoteType + Metrics + (1+PP|Font) + (1+Font|Item), ProfJData)
```

Wouldn't this mean that participants are grouped into `Font`? I'm uncertain about this as I usually see `PP` as a grouping factor in most papers.

Any clarification would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> lmer(Rating~Font*QuoteType + Metrics + (1+QuoteType|PP) + (1+Font|Item), ProfJData)
```

This looks OK.

> I specified `(1+QuoteType|PP)` as I imagined that every `PP`'s intercept will differ by `QuoteType`, and the same for Item.

This seems slightly confused. It is not that every *`PP`'s intercept will differ by `QuoteType`* - rather that every `PP` will have their own estimate for `QuoteType`. In other words you have random intercepts for `PP` (because it is a grouping variable) and you have random slopes for `QuoteType`. `QuoteType` is also a fixed effect which is perfectly normal, so there is a global "effect" of `QuoteType` (fixed effect) and random deviations from it for each `PP`.

> However, since `|` refers to "within each" - i.e, grouping variable- and since my `Font` variable is a between-subjects factor, should I not be specifying the model like so?

Again there is some confusion. You can read `|` as "within each" but it is important to know that on the right side you are specifying a grouping variable and fitting random intercepts for it. You have repeated measures within `Item` (because each item was viewed by all participants), and similarly for `PP`. What comes on the left side is a global fixed effect which is also allowed to vary at the diffeent levels of whatever is on the right.

> ```
> lmer(Rating~Condition*QuoteType + Metrics + (1+PP|Font) + (1+Font|Item), ProfJData)
> ```
>
> Wouldn't this mean that participants are grouped into Font?

No, it means that each level of `PP` would vary by the grouping factor `Font` which doesn't make sense.

> I'm uncertain about this as I usually see PP as a grouping factor in most papers.

Yes, you need `PP` as a grouping factor.

Comment: Thank you again for your helpful response. I was quite sure about my initial formula but came across a paper today that did indeed confuse my understanding of random effects. Your explanation has once again made things much more clearer.